# Targeting last listed object in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="patches">Patches</li>
    <ul id="patches_dropdown">
      <li><a href="new_patch.php">New</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target that last li with logout somehow, got myself confused was pretty close with li:last-child a:hover but then I target also last li from the previous unordered list.

```
ul:first-child li:last-child a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: FYI you can't have `<br />` as children of a `<ul>`.

Comment: what should I do instead? css margins or is there other way

Comment: check my answer again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following selector

```
#wrapper > ul > li:last-child a {
        color:red;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/87bvck9u/)**

```css
#wrapper > ul > li:last-child a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="patches">Patches</li>
    <ul id="patches_dropdown">
      <li><a href="new_patch.php">New</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: cheers mate although I'm not sure why do we use wrapper since they all belong to wrapper

Comment: @tktk - With your current markup you need the #wrapper in the selector because we only want to select the last list item of a list which is **a direct child of wrapper** (`#wrapper > ul...`) This is the part that excludes the last list item of the other `ul` from being selected

Answer (score 0):

**Last-of-type** targets the last type of element that it precedes. Just do something like this

```css
#wrapper > ul > li:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 25px;
  }

#wrapper > ul > li:last-of-type a {
  color: red;
  }

#wrapper > ul > li:last-of-type a:hover {
  color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="patches">Patches</li>
    <ul id="patches_dropdown">
      <li><a href="new_patch.php">New</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
   
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how about :hover i triend ul li:last-of-type:hover didn't seem to work

Comment: I've made the change to accommodate that

Comment: Tried that as well but it targets still the last li from the 2nd ul

Comment: Check  your html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#wrapper > ul > li:nth-last-of-type(1) a` or `#wrapper > ul > li:last-of-type a` or`#wrapper > ul > li:last-child a`.

```css
#wrapper > ul > li:nth-last-of-type(1) a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li id="patches">Patches</li>
    <ul id="patches_dropdown">
      <li><a href="new_patch.php">New</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with your selector to avoid selecting the other ULs in the page.

```
div#wrapper > ul > li:last-of-type a:hover {
    /* styles */
```

}

If both ULs are in the same wrapper, you can use:

```
div#wrapper > ul:first-of-type > li:last-of-type a:hover {
    /* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
#wrapper > ul > li:nth-child(2)
{
color:red;
}
```